# how to specify http or https proxy in clj-http in clojure

Tags: clojure, clj-http

In this url, it shows how to use proxy in clj-http

https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http

```
(client/get "http://foo.com" {:proxy-host "127.0.0.1" :proxy-port 8118})
```

But since we could have http proxy or https proxy, how to specify http or https? or it's mart enough to pickup the right now without the need to give http or https?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the per-request api, so you manually choose if the request has to use a proxy or not, so for that particular request it will always use a proxy no matter if it is http or https

Comment: I meant how the tell it to use http or https. You know there are many types of proxy, 2 of them are http and https, so how to use the api to select http or https

Comment: From https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/cc6f407033f65d7a22a18d65f3850e1424d35664/src/clj_http/core_old.clj#L91 it seems that it uses (getScheme target), so http for http, https for https